# Facebook Login Javascript API

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am testing a FB Login in my latest Website and it seems easy but when I try log in into a app it never returns all of a information.
I need at least a email but the variables in a response are only "id" and "name"

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '996648240391360', // Set YOUR APP ID
      //channelUrl : 'http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
{
 if (response.status === 'connected') 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
    //SUCCESS

}    
else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";

    //FAILED
} else 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";

    //UNKNOWN ERROR
}
}); 

};

function Login()
{

    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) 
       {
            getUserInfo();
        } else 
        {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
     },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});

}

function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

  var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.username+"<br>";
      str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
      str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
      str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

});
}
function getPhoto()
{
  FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

      var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;

});

}
function Logout()
{
    FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
}

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

</script>
```

Anyone could help me and tell why is not working?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yahmJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Facebook used to provide basic info(name, emailid, facebook id) of a user when the user grants access to public info of his/her profile. Facebook recently changed their permissions strategy, and hence you need to check with Facebook Permissions Page @ developer.facebook.com

Comment: How I able my app to receive email and other informations now?

Comment: You will have to send a request to facebook for that. The App dashboard of yours will have a section for "Status & Review". Check there if the permissions you need (of email) are approved.

Comment: Reviewing my app? Or email facebook developers group?

Comment: They are aprroved but it not shows on response how I said http://prntscr.com/8zs8yb

Comment: can you please send the output of GET /{user-id}/permissions using your oauth token for the account using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Comment: please share the output of
https://graph.facebook.com/<your facebook id>/permission?saccess_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET

Comment: APP_ID|APP_SECRET separted with symbol | ??

Comment: Did you try replacing this line `{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});` with `{scope: 'email'});`

Comment: Output response {"name":"Ricardo Pereira","id":"986303121434163"}